# Open-source ATI drivers&problems with gaming

Tags: ati, graphics, games

I recently installed Steam, and bought a few games, mainly to show support for games being ported to linux.

My problem is as follows:

My computer has an ATI mobility radeon HD 3400 video card, running on open source drivers. The games won't run when i try to run them(Faster Than Light crashes the system, The Cave just won't start). When i use the integrated intel chip as defaut graphics, this problem does not occur.

I previously tried to install proprietary drivers for ATI, but that was a disaster, so i reverted back to open source drivers

If anyone knows the reason for this error, and perhaps a solution for it, please share your info.
 [EDIT]: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit

Comment: Figure out the binary drivers or expect problems or degraded performance.  While binary drivers are a "sin" it's a white lie most of us commit for performance.

Comment: Thanks, i think i have to install ATI's own drivers. Or at least try to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm...

After some intensive research&digging, I am now strongly under the impression that the latest ATI proprietary drivers for ubuntu don't work with the 3.5 kernel and LTS 12.04.2.

Only options are to revert to the older kernel version or to wait for driver updates from ATI. There is hope, of course, that the OS ATI drivers will come up to speed in running games.

I hope this saves the time and frustration for people with similar issues.